# RecordIndex out of range

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am struggling with the DevExpress grid and was wondering if anybody's got a good tip on this one. This is the code causing me grief:

```
If GridView.Controller.SelectedRecordCount > 0 Then
Begin
    CurrentGridRow := GridView.DataController.GetRowID( 
                      GridView.Controller.SelectedRecords[ 0 ].RecordIndex );
End
Else
    CurrentGridRow := 0;
```

The exception gets raised when trying to get the row id and it's correct, because, well, this code is in a RefreshData method call and there has just been a change which made the record disappear from the grid.
Thus, what I need to solve this is some way to tell whether the recordindex is still valid.
I did have a look around but I can't find anything helpful and google didn't want to
share its goodies on this one.

Has anybody got a good tip on how to make sure the record index is valid?

Thank you very much!

Andrea

Comment: You may have more success posting this to the devexpress support forums....

Comment: I got the feeling you might be right, BUT I have been with the company for a very short time, I have no idea what the support account credentials are and I am sure that many knowledgeable people hang around here - hence worth a shot!

Comment: @Andrea - i agree with Marjan. The support provided by DevExpress is very good. Also see the extensive demos/Knowledge base/help online

Comment: DevExpress support is fast and efficient. The people are very nice and helps you until the end. :) I think posting there is better than here (in my experience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By delving a little in to the DevEx source I can see that GetRowID expects a `RowIndex` as parameter and not a `RecordIndex` as you are passing.

`RecordIndex` is, well, the index of a record in the internal DataSet of the grid. `RowIndex` is de index of a record as shown visually. So the top-most visible row of your grid has `RowIndex = 0`

Looking at your code I think you want `GetRowIndexByRecordIndex`. The visual index of the first selected record.

Comment: There should be a programming term, something like "integer fallacy" that covers the confusion coming from the mismatch of ordinal types, where "This integer index value does not mean what you think it means".

Comment: [RecordIndex on par with Microsoft's DLL debauchery](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q33881.aspx) ;-)

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that, too, but this is not code written by me and I am not fluent with DevExpress components, thus before changing it I must be *absolutely and completely sure* I am not destroying anything else - and I am not.

Comment: @Warren: Would be nice if one could use the `TRecordIndex = type Integer;` syntax to differentiate between two potential TRecordIndex and TRowIndex types.